# Trouble binding tables to Knockout collection

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I can't understand why these Knockout table bindings aren't working:

**Javascript:**

```
$(function () {

    var FileObject = function(id, name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    };

    var FilesModel = function() {

        this.filesSelected = ko.observable(false);  
        this.myFiles = ko.observableArray([new FileObject(1, 'test_1')]);
        this.myFiles.push(new FileObject(2, 'test_2'));
    };

    var filesModel = new FilesModel();
    window.filesModel = filesModel;
    ko.applyBindings(filesModel);

    filesModel.myFiles().push(new FileObject(3, 'test_3')); // This never shows

    alert(filesModel.myFiles().length); // Shows 3 items

});
```

**HTML:**

```
<h3>TABLE 1</h3>
<table> 
<tbody data-bind="foreach: myFiles">
    <tr>
        <td>FILE:</td>
        <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
    </tr>    
</tbody>
</table>

<h3>TABLE 2</h3>
<table>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: myFiles()">
    <tr>
        <td>FILE:</td>
        <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
    </tr>    
</tbody>
</table>
```

In both of these tables, the first 2 files will show, but the 3rd file doesn't. What am I missing?

Comment: Create a jsFiddle demonstrating the issue, should be a simple syntax error you are probably overlooking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're *really* close.  Two main things to point out:

1. Status isn't an observable, and you're attempting to unwrap it with `text: status()`.
2. You're pushing the new `FileObject` into an unwrapped array, meaning you're bypassing the observable altogether.  Push new items directly into the observable array, you'll have better luck.

I've put together a [jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/uhiSIqEH/1/) based on your original source.

Specifically, this:

```
filesModel.myFiles().push(new FileObject(3, 'test_3')); // This never shows
```

Should be:

```
filesModel.myFiles.push(new FileObject(3, 'test_3')); // Now it does
```

Comment: Unwrapped array was exactly the issue- Thanks @Ross!

Comment: (The status stuff was just my sloppy copy/paste- not relevant to question)

Comment: **BONUS:** So does it matter whether I do `data-bind="foreach: myFiles"` or `data-bind="foreach: myFiles()"`?

Comment: Off the top of my head - in this case, I don't think it matters.  Testing my memory, `myFiles` is called for (and unwrapped if needed) by the `foreach` after the change event has been fired from changing `myFiles`.  I'd have to go look around the guts to be certain, though.

Comment: @Yarin if you want to see the difference console.log(myFiles()) before and after you bind it in the view.  Specifically look at the observable's subscribers, that is where you make sure that you have registered the DOM element as a subscriber.

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML, you were trying to data-bind `status()`, but `status` is not an observable. One approach is to  make your `FileObject` members observables.
Also, your third `FileObject` was never showing because your syntax was wrong. Instead of `filesModel.myFiles().push`, it should be just `filesModel.myFiles.push`

See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rwisch45/6Lkv3/9/)

```
$(function () {
    var FileObject = function(id, name, size, status, progress) {
        this.id = ko.observable(id);
        this.name = ko.observable(name);
        this.status = ko.observable(status);
    };

    var FilesModel = function() {

        this.filesSelected = ko.observable(false);  
        this.myFiles = ko.observableArray([new FileObject(1, 'test_1')]);
        this.myFiles.push(new FileObject(2, 'test_2', 3, 'status'));
    };

    var filesModel = new FilesModel();
    window.filesModel = filesModel;
    ko.applyBindings(filesModel);

    filesModel.myFiles.push(new FileObject(3, 'test_3')); // This never shows

    alert(filesModel.myFiles().length); // Shows 3 items

});
```

Comment: @rwisch45- Thanks it was the syntax issue, Ross beat you by a few